# Can't override block content twig

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, silex

I'm trying to override the content of title block but with no success. Here is the situation.

## header.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>{% block pageTitle %}title{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
```

## layout.html.twig

```
 {% include 'header.html.twig' %}
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="page-wrapper">
    ........
```

## users.html.twig

```
 {% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
 {% block pageTitle %}Users{% endblock %}
```

At this point the page title is not changed as expected. I've readed that it is not possible to change the block when the template is 'included'.
The advice was to use embed instead. When I change include to embed I get

```
A template that extends another one cannot have a body in
```

Any ideas how to manage it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably comes from layout.html.twig, you need to define a body block, ie:

```
    {% block body %}
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="page-wrapper">

    [...]
    {% endblock %}
```

[`embed` combines the behavior of `include` & `extends`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html)

Comment: When I add block body I get 
Unexpected token "end of template" of value ""

Comment: Check to see if you forgot to close a block or the embed tag.

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe the use `embeded` instead :*

```
{% embed 'layout.html.twig' %}
    {% block pageTitle %}Users{% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

**doc :** http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't overwrite included blocks, you can only extend them.

You can solve this by changing just a bit your architecture:

## layout.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>{% block pageTitle %}title{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block pageBody %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

## users.html.twig

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}

{% block pageTitle %}Users{% endblock %}

{% block pageBody %}
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            (...)
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

## [demo](http://twigfiddle.com/hkrkpo)